# Python - part of str [urllib3 data]

Tags: python-3.x, urllib3

I'm Trying to delete 2 chars from start of the str and 1 char from the end

```
import urllib3
target_url="www.klimi.hys.cz/nalada.txt"

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', target_url)
print(r.status)
print(r.data)
print()
```

And Output is

```
200
b'smutne'
```

I need to output be only "smutne", only this, not the " b' " and " ' "

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: Have you checked any string operations? Like [`slicing`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

Comment: but this isn's a string so i cant work with like a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have bytes, you'll need them to *decode* it into a string with the appropriate encoding type. For example, if you have a ASCII characters as bytes, you can do:

```
>>> foo = b'mystring'
>>> print(foo)
b'mystring'
>>> print(foo.decode('ascii'))
'mystring'
```

Or, more commonly, you probably have Unicode characters (which includes most of the ASCII character codes too):

```
>>> print(foo.decode('utf-8'))
'mystring'
```

This will work if you have glyphs with accents and such.

More on Python encoding/decoding here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

In the particular case of urllib3, `r.data` returns bytes that you'll need to decode in order to use as a string if that's what you want.